# How to use F1 key to launch Terminal?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I recently installed debian 7.5.

In ubuntu I configured my <kbd>F1</kbd> key to launch `gnome-terminal` with no problems In system settings and keyboard shortcuts.

Now in my debian I try to do the same but the launcher is substituted for <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>` and it still doesn't work in debian. It did in Ubuntu.

My pc is an HP and I must use the <kbd>fn</kbd> key to execute the <kbd>F[1-12]</kbd> keys. I don't want to disable it since I didn't while using ubuntu.

**How can I add this shortcut?**

How come I did this on ubuntu with no problem? Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm, currently you have to press Fn + Super + F1 to bring up the terminal, but you want to just press Fn + F1?

Comment: I want to use F1 only. Right now It doesn't work with any combination. Not even Fn + Super + F1

Comment: I'm presuming your Ubuntu install had different ACPI settings and/or HP-specific keyboard drivers installed to handle that, which your Debian install does not have. Can you post the output of `showkey -s` when you press F1, Fn+F1, Super+F1, and Fn+Super+F1? Can you also tell us what model PC you have (and/or what keyboard you have if it's not the stock keyboard)?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, try `modprobe hp_wmi` (or `hp-wmi`, not sure) and see if that gets your keys working.

Comment: this is the output of showkey:`^[OP0xe0 0x5b 0x3b 0xe0 0xdb 0xbb`

Comment: and modprobe worked fine. My keys are working fine but still cant get the shortcut to work

Comment: `0x3B` is the correct scan code for F1. Did the `0xE0 0x5B` sequence result from you pressing F1 alone?

Comment: Yup. All that came from pressing F1 alone

Comment: Ok, well at least we know that you pressing F1 results in the system actually seeing "Super+F1". That's a start. I'll look around some more or maybe somebody else can chime in. `E0 5B 3B` is Super+F1 press, `E0 DB BB` is Super+F1 release. So your keys seem to be functioning correctly wrt. the Fn key, but the Super is stuck in there for some reason.

Comment: Can the shurtcuts be done in any config file from terminal?